# How to permanently allow an RDS instance to connect to my server?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, iptables, firewall, rds

I'm using [an Amazon RDS instance as a slave](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html) to replicate my bare metal MySQL server, as a backup.

I'm authorizing the RDS  instance's IP in my server's firewall this way:

```
# iptables \
  --insert INPUT \
  --source xxxxxxx.yyyyyyy.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
  --protocol tcp \
  --destination-port mysql \
  --jump ACCEPT
```

This works fine, however `iptables` resolves the instance's host to its EC2 counterpart, and stores this one instead:

```
# iptables --list
...

ACCEPT  tcp  --  ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com  anywhere  tcp  dpt:mysql
```

The problem is, whenever the RDS instance is restarted/modified/upgraded, **it's usually moved to another EC2 instance**, so even though the `*.rds.amazonaws.com` host stays the same, the `*.compute.amazonaws.com` host changes, and **the RDS instance loses the connection to my server.**

The solution involves, right now, a manual intervention from me to re-issue the `iptables` command.

**Is there a solution to permanently allow incoming connections from an IP, as long as a domain in the firewall configuration resolves to this IP?**

I'd accept a solution involving `firewalld` as well.

Answer (score 2):

No. (Linux) firewalls are IP driven, not domain name driven, and and domains used are resolved when the firewall is loaded/reloaded - to do otherwise would massively impact performance.

Firewalld won't help as its a really a wrapper around iptables.

You may have some luck by frequently reloading the firewall rules or doing checks and removing and reading the appropriate rule if changes occur using a script (eg via crontab).